# ArrayAdapter.clear() invokes on a null object reference

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I have the following code in an AsyncTask that retrieves a list of notifications from a DB.

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<NotificationItem> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (dialog.isShowing()) 
        dialog.dismiss();
    if (adpt != null) {
        if (result != null && result.size() > 0)
            adpt.setItemList(result);
        else if (adpt.getItemList() != null) 
            adpt.clear();
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    srl.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

As you can see, I check the result, the adapter (adpt) and its items (adpt.getItemList()) for being null, before making the relevant action such as .clear(). I want to clear the list when the result size is 0 meaning nothing should be shown to the user (before, it did). When the debug is on the .clear() line, all three objects are not null but still I get NullPointerException.

When debugging inside clear(), I got inside ArrayAdapter.java:

```
public void clear() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mOriginalValues != null) {
                mOriginalValues.clear();
            } else {
                mObjects.clear();
            }
        }
        if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And both mOriginalValues and mObjects are null, hence the error. Not sure what am I doing wrong, can you see the problem?

Update: I instantiate the adapter like this: `notificationsAdapter = new NotificationsAdapter(null);` ofcourse I do this as first step when I still don't have any items.

The error is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void java.util.List.clear()' on a null object reference at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258) at
>   com.example.example.fragments.NotificationsList$NotificationsRetriever.onPostExecute(NotificationsList.java:184)

Comment: What are `mOriginalValues`, `mLock` and `mObjects` ? Where do you assign values to them? Also consider having only one statement per line, it will really increase the readability of your code.

Comment: do you mind telling how you instantiate your adapter? and probably showing the NPE error

Comment: I updated my post. mOriginalValues, mLock and mObjects are of ArrayAdapter.java class and are not mind so i don't assign values to them directly

Comment: NotificationsAdapter??? Are you subclassing ArrayAdapter? If so, please post that code.